# How to save a dropdownlist selection back to the database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

My dropdown is pulling and displaying the correct list, however once selected, I click save and the selected option is disregarded and once again the value is empty.

//get

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    Prospect prospect = db.Prospects.Find(id);
    if (prospect == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    ViewBag.ProductID = new SelectList(db.Products, "ProductID", "Name", prospect.Product);
    return View(prospect);
}
```

//post

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Prospect prospect)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(prospect).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        ViewBag.ProductID = new SelectList(db.Products, "ProductID", "Name", prospect.Product);
        return View(prospect);
    }
```

//view

```
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Product)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("ProductId", String.Empty)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Product)
    </div>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Can you show what is your `Prospect` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

only for helpers (except display) are tied to the model.  change your drop down list to

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ProductID, (SelectList)ViewBag.ProductID)
```

where ProductID is whatever value in your model you want the selected item tied to.  You also set the drop down this way by setting that value before passing it to the view

Update:

I agree with Muffin Mans answer.  Using ViewBag to send drop down lists to the view can be unreliable.  A different way to put the answer the muffin man provided

Add an list to your model

```
public List<SelectListItem> Products { get; set; }
```

then on your controller populate that list from the database.  Muffin Man provided one way to do it.  We access our data differently so I populate my list with a foreach

```
var products = //populate the list from your database
List<SelectListItem> ls = new List<SelectListItem>();
foreach(var temp in products){
    ls.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = temp.ProductName, Value = temp.ProductID });
}
Model.Products = ls; // set the list in your model to the select list you just built
```

then on your view instead of casting a view bag list to a select list you can just reference the list from the model

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ProductID, Model.Products)
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you for your time, also thank you for the other contributors, I initially got an error after missing the 'For' in dropdownlist and moved onto Muffin Man's, however I was thoroughly lost after a minute and thankfully saw the additional 'For'.  Thanks again all and have a great day.

Comment: This answer is sloppy. No guidance is given on the total solution that you provided. If Matt wants to update his answer to give you best practice advice I'll be happy to remove the down vote.

Comment: @TheMuffinMan I am not sure how an answer that uses the setup that he has and fixes his issue is sloppy.  I completely agree with how you set up your answer (mine is the upvote on your answer).  As requested, I have provided a suggestion on a better way to do it

Comment: Maybe sloppy is a bit extreme, and yes you did answer his question and I assume it works, however I think that if you're going to provide the direct answer you should say this will solve your problem, but it's not the right way to do it and provide the right way. I could see by the code that he provided that he has a weak understanding of all of this and could really use some help. So with that being said I will remove the downvote and upvote you.

Comment: @TheMuffinMan Completely agree with you sir.  Thank you for your advice and for the upvote :)

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be tying your view directly to your database table type. Use a view model. Additionally this type of data belongs in your view model, not the viewbag. The view bag is great for sharing things like page title between your view and the layout page.

```
public class ProspectViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ProspectList { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Product")] //This is for our label
    public int SelectedProspectId { get; set; }
}
```

Get

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
   var prospect = db.Prospects.Find(id);
   if (prospect == null)
   {
       return HttpNotFound();
   }

   var model = new ProspectViewModel
                   {
                      ProductList = db.Products.Select(x=> new SelectListItem { ... })
                   };

   return View(model);
}
```

Post

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(ProspectViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var prospect = new Prospect { /* populate with values from model */  };
        db.Prospects.Attach(prospect);
        db.Entry(prospect).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    //Need to repopulate drop down list
    //And we don't need to set SelectedProductId because it's already been posted back
    model.ProductList = db.Products.Select(x=> new SelectListItem { ... });

    return View(model);
}
```

View

```
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SelectedProductId)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x=> x.SelectedProductId, Model.ProductList)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x=> x.SelectedProductId)
</div>
```

This is outside the scope of this answer, but you shouldn't be doing data access within your controller. Microsoft's examples show this because they are meant to be "Hello world" examples, not necessarily to be taken literally.